# How do you get the folder from where the file is from in Google Drive to display in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently the code I have displays just the file name, file url source, and file type, I tried using getFolder() but that does not seem to be working for me, this is what I have so far. Any ideas on how best to implement the folder functions (if needed or not) in order to display in a separate column where each file is from folder-wise?

```
function search(Phrase, FolderID) {
  // Prompt the user for a search term
  var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the string to search for:");

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var headers = [["File Name", "File Type", "URL"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);

  // Search the files in the user's Google Drive for the search term based on if the word is included in thefile or name
  // Search Reference Guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("fullText contains '"+searchTerm.replace("'","\'")+"'");
  //var SearchString = 'fullText contains "' + Phrase + '" and "' + FolderID + '" in parents';
  //var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(SearchString);
  // create an array to store our data to be written to the sheet 
  var output = [];
  // Loop through the results and get the file name, file type, and URL
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    var name = file.getName();
    var type = file.getMimeType();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    // push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data)
    output.push([name, type, url]);
  }
  // write data to the sheet
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, 3).setValues(output);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function search(Phrase, FolderID) {
  // Prompt the user for a search term
  var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the string to search for:");

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var headers = [["File Name", "File Type", "URL", "Folder"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:D1").setValues(headers);

  // Search the files in the user's Google Drive for the search term based on if the word is included in thefile or name
  // Search Reference Guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("fullText contains '"+searchTerm.replace("'","\'")+"'");
  //var SearchString = 'fullText contains "' + Phrase + '" and "' + FolderID + '" in parents';
  //var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(SearchString);
  // create an array to store our data to be written to the sheet 
  var output = [];
  // Loop through the results and get the file name, file type, and URL
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    var name = file.getName();
    var type = file.getMimeType();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    var folderNames = "";
    var folders = file.getParents();
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = folders.next();
        Logger.log(folder.getName());
        folderNames += folder.getName() + ", ";
    }
    // push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data)
    output.push([name, type, url, folders]);
  }
  // write data to the sheet
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, 4).setValues(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a file's folder with the method `getParents()`.
In you code, it could look like:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    var name = file.getName();
    var type = file.getMimeType();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    var folderNames = "";
    var folders = file.getParents();
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = folders.next();
        folderNames += folder.getName() + ", ";
    }
    // push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data)
    output.push([name, type, url, folderNames]);
  }
```

The other methods of the class file can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Comment: I implemented the code you suggested;however all the folders names are returning as "FolderIterator". Could this be because the files are within folders that are within another folder and it's confuding the code? Any suggestions? *Editted post to show implementation*

Comment: I realise there is a typo in my answer, it sould be `folderNames += folder.getName() + ", ";`, not `=`. It might be causing the issue. If you try logging the name instead of adding it, does it work?

Comment: I changed it to a +; however the same problem remains that it still returns FolderIterator

Comment: try `Logger.log(folder.getName());` in the loop and check if it logs the names correctly. Btw in your question it's `==`, not `+` :)

Comment: The Logs do have the correct folder names there, it's just not printing/displaying on the sheet correctly, still shows as FolderIterator on the google sheet, also I updated my original post for clarity on the new changes.

Comment: Ahh I see, its the `output.push([name, type, url, folders]);` that is wrong, it should be `folderNames` instead of `folders` there.